# How to use a standalone WSClient in a Scala application

Tags: scala, playframework

I would like to use `ws` in a standalone application. Trying this code, copied from https://gist.github.com/cdimascio/46b2b7d2986636c1189c :

```
import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig
import play.api.libs.ws.ning._
import play.api.libs.ws._

// provide an execution context
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object WSStandaloneTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // set up the client
    val config = new NingAsyncHttpClientConfigBuilder(DefaultWSClientConfig()).build
    val builder = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder(config)
    val client = new NingWSClient(builder.build)

    // execute a GET request
    val response = client.url("http://www.example.com").get

    // print the response body
    response.foreach(r => {
      println(r.body) 
      // not the best place to close the client, 
      // but it ensures we dont close the threads before the response arrives 
      // Good enough for the gist :-D
      client.close()
    })
  }
}
```

Results in the following error:

```
[error] object ning is not a member of package play.api.libs.ws
[error] import play.api.libs.ws.ning._
```

In my `build.sbt` I have this:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.6.1"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First have a look at https://github.com/playframework/play-ws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NingWSClient](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.18/api/java/play/libs/ws/ning/NingWSClient.html) is deprecated in Play! 2.5.x.

In 2.6.x

> The `ning` package has been replaced by the `ahc` package, and the `Ning`* classes replaced by AHC*.

There is a migration guide available in the [official doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/WSMigration26).

So you can choose to downgrade to 2.5.x and use `ning` or update the code.